# How to join array items into single string per row in Google Apps Script?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am wanting to envision the below in Google Sheets, where I can run a script to check Column A against three lists, and the output in Column G will state from what lists the values in Column A appeared in:

[image: Ideal Result]

I am already able to produce this effect via a very inefficient set of nested loops, setValue(), and getValue().

However, I'm aware that there are more optimal ways of going about it, such as appending items via arrays.

I am not very familiar with the syntax of Google Apps Script arrays, so I'd like guidance on how to go about this. I've written the below so far:

```
function list_function()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var check_list = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var list_A = sheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
  var list_B = sheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues();
  var list_C = sheet.getRange("E1:E").getValues();
  
  var checking_array = [];
  
  for(var i=1; i<check_list.length; i++)

  {

//list A here
for (var j = 1; j < list_A.length; j++)
{
  if (check_list[i][0] != "" && check_list[i][0].toUpperCase() == list_B[j][0].toUpperCase())
  {
  
    checking_array.push(['List_A"']);
  }
}

//List B here
   for (var k = 1; k < list_B.length; k++)
{
  if (check_list[i][0] != "" && check_list[i][0].toUpperCase() == list_B[k][0].toUpperCase())
  {
    checking_array.push(['List_B"']);
  }
}

  //List C here
   for (var l = 1; l < list_C.length; l++)
{
  if (check_list[i][0] != "" && check_list[i][0].toUpperCase() == list_C[l][0].toUpperCase())
  {
    checking_array.push(['List_C"']);
  }
}
//Problem here, not sure how to join() array items into single string value for cell and match according to list 
//ideally matches the above picture
    sheet.getRange(1, 7, check_list.length).setValues(checking_array);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By the way, the image of your question is the input situation?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi, the question/goal is to achieve the image, specifically outputting Column G's results, via arrays/lists if this is possible. My intention was to push an item to an array list per each column having met the value in Column A, and then combine all listed items per row into a single string. The single string would be set within the same row of Column G, then iterate again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the values of the entire spreadsheet at once, and get values or set values:

```
function list_function()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues(); //getRange(starting Row, starting column, number of rows, number of columns)
  
 
  var check = "";

  var dataValue;
  var checkValue;
     
//All lists here
    for (var i = 1; i < lastRow; i++)  { 
           checkValue =  data[i][0];
           for (var j = 2; j < lastColumn - 2; j++)
           {
             for (var k=1 ; k< lastRow;  k++){
               dataValue =  data[k][j];
               if (dataValue.toUpperCase() === checkValue.toUpperCase() )
                {
                   check=check + "," + data[0][j];
                }
             }
             
           } 
           data[i][lastColumn-1]=check.slice(1);
           check = "";
     } 
    
    
   check = "x"; // set breakpoint here to check data[][] values before write
   sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).setValues(data);
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, though I was hoping to go about the problem via arrays/lists for large sets of data. I have two questions about your answer: 1) why do we need to set check = "x" if it has been reset to "" at the end of the loop? 2) is there a way to optimize the method, because I can imagine the loops to take much longer when it comes to processing a larger list of data?

Comment: You can get rid of the check = "x"; it was for debugging.  How big is your dataset? I find that the slowest part in scripts are the calls to the SpreadsheetApp, and not the processing of the loops.  I just tried my script on a 500x16 expanded data spreadsheet, and it was still fast at 2.1 seconds.

Comment: It's probably a combination of my large datasets and separate calls to different spreadsheets, then. My original data sets would have had List A, List B, and List C across separate sheets, and at +2000 rows each. Whatever the case, thanks for the template. I think it's more of a matter of optimization for me, then.